# Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload

while uploading multiple files I am unable to retrieve them from $event.target.files

```
<form> 
    <input type="file" (change)="onuploadFile($event.target.files)" multiple />
</form>
```

typescript:

```
  onuploadFile( files : File[]): void{
    console.log(files)
  }
```

error:

```
Object is possibly 'null'.
Property 'files' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```html
<form> 
    <input type="file" (change)="onuploadFile($any($event.target).files)" multiple />
</form>
```

Read more [here](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-eventtarget-error-in-angular/)